# c++20 why can't I "pipe" into views::reverse like the other views functions?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am testing some of the fancy new c++ features, one of which is ranges and the associated views. I find it particularly interesting that you can chain what you wish to do with a container.

You can use the binary `operator|()` to chain things, which is really nice. I noticed that you can chain into `std::views::take(int)`, `std::views::transform()` with a lambda or function pointer, `std::views::filter()` with a lambda or function pointer. The only thing you can't use is std::views::reverse. That one can only be used by putting a range into it's argument. Why it that? Is there an alternative?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
  using std::string;
  using std::cout, std::endl;
  
  const std::vector<string> vec = { "A", "B", "a", "b", "b2", "a2", "a3", "b3", "b4" };
  
  for (auto const& val : std::views::reverse(vec) // ok
                      | std::views::take_while([](const string& s) {return s.size() > 0 && s[0] == 'b'; })
                      // | std::views::reverse() // Error?!
    )
  {
    cout << val << endl;
  }
}
```

Compile with `g++ -std=c++20 main.cpp -o main`
How would I get `b3`, `b4` in that situation using the syntax above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for piping into single-argument adaptors isn't:

```cpp
| views::reverse()
```

It's

```cpp
| views::reverse
```

No parentheses in this case. `std::views::reverse(a)` could be written as `a | std::views::reverse` to start with as well.

Similar for all the other single-argument range adaptors (`join`, `keys`, `values`, `elements<N>`, etc.).